# How to convert below string into proper json format in java?

Tags: json

How to convert below string into proper json format in java?

"{1=1183,1084={1=264,11=hello,482=1,481=Ram},268=nil,535=crons,63=93,402=time}"

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ':' instead of = and variable name instead of numbers

Comment: {1:1183,1084:<rec>{1:264,11:tamju,482:1,481:05c11cfd-85e1-4e10-9dad-65ae806a90bc},268:nil,535:Agency,63:93,402:ARRIVAL}